# How to sort an array of hashmaps in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small question regarding the sorting of a JavaScript array.

I have an array which holds basically a hashmap: 
`dataOfTheUserArray=new Array(6);`, which is basically an array of hashmaps.
The map looks like the following:

```
keys:              values

Symbol              xyz
NumberOfStocks      1o
Price               200
```

So the array basically contains a map for each symbol.

Now I want to sort the array based on the price of the stock .
So what I did was:

```
dataOfTheUserArray.sort(sortByPriceBought);

//The call back function is
function sortByPriceBought(a, b) {

    var x = a.Price;
    var y = b.Price;
    return ((x >y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

After sorting it when I iterate through the array the highest price is in the first and all the rest is not sorted.
Is there something I am doing wrong?
I would really appreciate if someone can explain if anything went wrong in the code.

Answer (score 3):

If property, a.Price is a string object, the ordering is made lexically.

Changing the code as follows may solve your problem:

```
var x = parseInt(a.Price);
var y = parseInt(b.Price);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your sorting function using `-` instead of conditions:

```
function sortByPriceBought(a, b) {
    return b.Price - a.Price;
}
```

Make sure, than all elements of array have `Price` property.